# Type mismatch: cannot convert from Connection to Connection

Tags: java, jdbc

I want  JDBC connection to MSaccess.
But

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:access");
```

it gives

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Connection to Connection

what is solution for that?

I m using Servlet and jsp
in jsp -

```
Organization Name:    <input type="text"  name="Organization_name" ><br>
```

i want when Organization_name entered it will be add it in my access **database**
i have tried but i m facing  following problem

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:access");
```

it gives **Type mismatch: cannot convert from Connection to Connection**

Comment: What does your import say for Connection?

Answer (score 5):

you need `Connection` from `java.sql` it seems you have imported a wrong class

and `getConnection()` needs complete jdbc `URL`.

In very simple words your code should have following imports

`import java.sql.Connection`

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager; 

...

try { 
   String username = "";
   String password = "";
   Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:northwind", username, password);
   ...
```

northwind is the name of the sample database in Access. Use whatever you've got.

Answer (score 0):

The `Connection` object that is being returned by `getConnection()` is not the same `Connection` class you have referenced in your package imports at the top of your class file.

Comment: FYI: This could be caused by a bad import or by using a different class loader then the one used by the returned object.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an classloader issue. The object created is from  the different classloader and is referred in another classloader.