# Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.sql.Connection to com.mysql.jdbc.Connection

Tags: mysql, servlets, jdbc

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.mysql.jdbc.*;

*// Here,in below 2 statement, I got 2 the same error as shown in title*

**Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("localhost:3306", "root","simple");               
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();**
    if(stmt.execute(sql)){
    System.out.println("Sql Statement Executed.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Sql Statement not eexecuted.");
    }
    if((unm != null) && (pwd != null)){
        RequestDispatcher rd =request.getRequestDispatcher("Home.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
}

}
```

I am  trying to send my data from servlet to mysql server but in servlet I got the

error : "Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.sql.Connection to com.mysql.jdbc.Connection"

Can anyone suggest me the way to remove the error for  my code. I am not getting any idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the `import com.mysql.jdbc.*` 
and use `import java.sql.Connection`. I think it would be ok.

Comment: Yes, it is even works but I want to use mysql as a back-end tool and the DriverManager can  not be resolved error still come..

Comment: In Hurry ness, I forgot, it's a Connection interface provided in javase spec which handle the object given by DriverManger>getConnection()...!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using the wrong connection string and the driver manager doesn't know how to instantiate the connection. The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html#connector-j-examples-connection-drivermanager) has more info about the format.

It think the code should be something like

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test","root","simple");
```

And I think there's a problem with the imports, as described in this other question: [Type mismatch: cannot convert from Connection to Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126900/type-mismatch-cannot-convert-from-connection-to-connection), and you need to `import java.sql.Connection;`

edit

To fix the DriverManager error you need to register the driver with the following code (taken from the mysql documentation)

```
    try {
        // The newInstance() call is a work around for some
        // broken Java implementations

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // handle the error
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Augusto for you reply, Yes it is resolved but still I got "DriverManager can not be resolved" error..

Comment: you probably haven't registered the mysql driver. Please read this [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html)

Answer (score 0):

try import **java.sql.Connection and java.sql.*** I hope it will work. Also I had gotten this error I try lot of ways to solve it but I got it also from your quiz in this page. And I was able to solve it.

THANK YOU ALL LIFE SAVER

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I am answering an old question but I ran into the same issue and I resolved it by importing all the libraries:

```
import java.io.*; import javax.servlet.*; import javax.servlet.http.*; import java.sql.*;
```

Hope it helps.